# Hello, I'am asking about hibernate.properties and dataSource bean

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, java-ee-6

I want to put hibernate.properties variables in the dataSource bean (Spring) properties, so, how can I do it, cause I have to deliver my application and it shouldn't contain much properties in different places. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The first you get a Spring managed datasource.
The second you get a hibernate managed datasource which is not reusable by Spring.

If you have a hibernate.properties in your classpath, the Spring LocalSessionFactoryBean will use that file to configure the database connections, dialect and pooling. Alternatively, you can define a DataSource in Spring (any class that implements javax.sql.DataSource) and explicity set all of your Hibernate properties in the LocalSessionFactoryBean (or AnnotationSessionFactoryBean if you are using annotation).

**1st Approach:**

Loading Hibernate properties: Hibernate properties can be loaded using Spring’s PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer class. Provide hibernate.properties file location as value. If the file placed under any other directory other than WEB-INF directory, use classpath: expression to let the Spring to look for the file in available classpath.

```
<!– Hibernate Properties –>
  <bean id=”PropertyConfigurer” class=”org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer”>
     <property name=”locations”>
       <list>
              <value>classpath:/properties/hibernate.properties</value>
       </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

**2nd Approach:**  http://wiki.apache.org/tapestry/SpringHibernate

```
<bean id="mySessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.
annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>com.xyz.domain.User</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect"> org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```